# Why are only a few video games written in Java?

Tags: java

Why aren't many commercial, 3D video games (not random open source 2D ones) written in Java? In theory, it makes a lot of sense: you get a productivity boost and a cross-platform application almost for free, among other things, such as the vast amount of Java libraries, and built-in garbage collection (although I admit I'm not sure if the latter is a good thing). So why is it rarely used? I can only think of a couple popular commercial games written for the Java platform.

Is it because of performance? If so, wouldn't most of the heavy lifting be done by the GPU anyway?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_trouble

Comment: Re: mmyers; I'm somewhat in shock that THAT game won a "best graphics" award, even in 2005...

Comment: Aaron: GameTunnel reviews mostly indie games.

Comment: I've never played it myself; is it that bad?

Comment: Yeah but most "real games" aren't made in managed .net right?  They're made in old school c/c++?

Comment: Runescape is written in java.

Comment: I went to a presentation once, I think at IBM.  Some company had written a custom Garbage collector for Java which went with lots of fast collections instead of a few slow collections, specifically intended to solve the blocking garbage collection issues people are talking about.  The presenter spoke about realtime applications in general rather than mentioning games.  I'm pretty sure this garbage collector costs money, though.

Comment: Runescape has done an amazing job with Java.

Comment: Minecraft is written in Java!

Comment: @Brian Appears that JDK7 has the GC1 garbage collector available now, which is designed to "never block" though I've heard it's a bit slower overall than the default GC. FWIW.

Comment: For future readers:[an interesting comparison on speed and memory usage between languages](http://raid6.com.au/~onlyjob/posts/arena/)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The game development world is a funny one: On one hand, they're often quick to accept new ideas, on the other hand, they're still in the stone age.

The truth is, there's rarely that much incentive in switching to .NET/Java/anything other than C/C++.

Most game companies license parts of the game engine from other companies. These parts are written in C++, and although you might have access to the source so you could port it, that takes a lot of effort (and of course, the license needs to allow it).

Also, a lot of legacy code already exists in C++. If code from previous projects can be reused (say, if you're writing a sequel), that counts even more in favor of sticking with the same language, instead of rewriting it in a new language (more so since you'll likely reintroduce a ton of bugs which you'll need to spend time ironing out.

Finally, it's rare for games to be written in 100% C++ anyway - a lot is done using scripting languages, whether they're custom or just integrating an existing languages (Lua being one of the more popular ones these days).

As far as garbage collection is concerned, that can be a bit of a problem. The problem is not so much that it exists, it's more how it works - the garbage collector MUST be non-blocking (or at least be guaranteed to only block very briefly), since it's simply unacceptable to have the game freeze for 10 seconds while it scans all the allocated memory to see what can be freed. I know Java tends to choke quite a bit in GC'ing when it's close to running out of memory (and for some games out there, it will).

You're also a bit more restricted in what you can do: you can't fully exploit the hardware due to the overhead of the runtime. Imagine Crysis being written in Java... even if that's the only visible difference, it just wouldn't be the same (I'm also pretty sure you'd need a Core i7 to run it.).

This doesn't mean these languages don't have their place in game development - and no, I'm not just referring to tool programming. For most games, you don't need that extra bit of performance you get from C++, including 3D games, and if you're writing it all from scratch, it can make perfect sense to use something like XNA - in fact, there's a good chance it will.

As far as commercial games are concerned - does [RuneScape](http://runescape.com) count? That may well be the most succesful Java game out there.

Comment: Well obviously you wouldn't run Crysis on the JVM; hell, if you coded that game in assembly language you'd still need a supercomputer to run it on full settings. But +1 for the excellent insight, thank you.

Comment: You can't compare Unreal Tournament 3 or Crysis with Runescape. If graphic quality is a concern, you need to stick with a low level language with as little overhead as possible. Of course, for Indy or games where graphics are not the main selling point, Java is an excellent alternative to C/C++.

Comment: @GuiSim: For most games, graphics quality is NOT a major selling point. There are only a handful of games I can think of that were created with graphics in mind (I'm thinking of Crysis, but Half-Life 2 as well, at the time). I don't think most game developers care that much about graphics, as long as they are "good enough" (aka on par with most other games).

Comment: Graphics really have very little to do with the language. Physics, AI, yes. Graphics, no.

Comment: Funny you should mention Crysis... http://www.mobileshop.com/blog/mobile-phone-news/experience-the-graphical-brilliance-of-crysis-on-a-mobile-phone/

Comment: @JulianR there can be a significant workload for preparing and maintaining a scene to be rendered efficiently, so the language and associated language overhead does matter for graphics.

Comment: Michael, read about GC vs malloc runtime behaviour...

Comment: I'm familiar with minecraft, but do you honestly believe (now this is a real question, not meant to be attacking) that Crysis would run with the same performance characteristics if it were all in java versus in C, disregarding GC?  That's my question.  Also note the G1 GC (java 7) is nonblocking.

Comment: @rogerdpack: No, not at all, but not every game tries to be as good-looking as Crysis.

Comment: As of today, we may want to add MineCraft.

Answer (score 95):

I think John Carmack said it best with:

> The biggest problem is that Java is really slow. On a pure cpu / memory / display / communications level, most modern cell phones should be considerably better gaming platforms than a Game Boy Advanced. With Java, on most phones you are left with about the CPU power of an original 4.77 mhz IBM PC, and lousy control over everything.
>   [...snip...]
>   Write-once-run-anywhere. Ha. Hahahahaha. We are only testing on four platforms right now, and not a single pair has the exact same quirks. All the commercial games are tweaked and compiled individually for each (often 100+) platform. Portability is not a justification for the awful performance.

([source](http://www.armadilloaerospace.com/n.x/johnc/recent%20updates/archive?news_id=295))

Granted, he was talking about mobile platforms, but I've found similar problems with Java as a whole coming from a C++ background.
I miss being able to allocate memory on the Stack/Heap on my own terms.

Comment: a source for your quote might be a good thing

Comment: +1 for the John Carmac reference. :)

Comment: Thanks for adding the source for me - I'll be more considerate in the future =)

Comment: That quote was from 2005. Both Java technology and Cellphone power has considerably improved since then. Comparing cellphone gaming vs PC gaming is comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: John Carmack said it. Case closed.

Comment: I suppose I could have also added the quote from one of his QuakeCon speeches where he said that Java is a good way to make your game 10x slower, but I couldn't find a transcript to quote.

Comment: I concede to the fact that you can run graphics intensive code faster in C than you can in Java. However, 9 times out of 10, when people say Java is slow compared to C/C++, the project they're currently coding in C/C++ would have performed just fine had it been written in Java

Comment: That may be true for some applications, but we are talking about full 3d games here and aren't starting a flame war.

Comment: I just get uneasy when I read "Java is really slow". It's like saying a $50k sports car is slow compared to a $100k sports car. Sure, it's slower, but 90% of the time, the job it does is still great and at half the cost ;) No flame war intended. I agree that the above reasons are why Crysis and like-games are not written in Java.

Comment: It's all good. On the flip side, I can get just as (if not more) defensive when people start quoting those flawed/skewed java vs C benchmarks and claiming that the era of C/C++ is dead. Glad we could meet half-way =P

Comment: I'd say there's a rather large difference between an interpreted (presumably, the article seems to hint at it) J2ME and the JIT or statically compiled Java running on the Sun VM..

Comment: @Chris Dail, this underscores the whole issue with Java performance. Has Java performance improved? No, cell phones just got faster. Games are supposed to push the limits of realism, and therefore push the limits of hardware, and throwing away %30-%40 of your performance before you've even written a line of code is unacceptable.

Comment: Chris Dail: Yes, Cellphone power has improved and now we have great games on mobile phones, but wait, this great games are made in C/C++(Objective-C is C/C++ too, so...), java is slow as he**, I'm ok with using it for drawing a widget and some text on it but it's a nightmare when it comes to something serious...

Comment: I find this dispute very strange. Java ME is not the same as Java in Android and also not the same as Java on PCs. Java ME usually relied on phone manufacturers to come up with a JVM. Some did good job, some didn't. No wonder Carmack was complaining about them. Android has it's own VM which is not a JVM. And it has some serious issues (from my point of view). Oracle's HotSpot VM is completely different from both cases. If people compare all these things, the only thing I can conclude is that they don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: Please note that the Java John Carmack was talking about was a tiny and slow implementation running on restricted devices _before_ the iPhone came on the scene with full GPU accelleration.  All modern games utilize the GPU regardless of platform.

Comment: Can you control the stack at run time?

Answer (score 55):

For one thing, Java's lack of operator overloading makes all of the math you have to deal with to get a working graphics pipeline very, very annoying and hard to read.

All of the matrix multiplication and affine vectors you need to deal with are a lot easier to follow if they're in well-formed mathematical expressions rather than object-oriented expressions like

```
product = vector.multiply(projectionMatrix).dotProduct(otherVector);
```

That's just terrible. Math shouldn't look like that.

Comment: I remember back in '96 I think it was, some of the designers from Sun were giving a presentation on Java at Berkeley.  William Kahan (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan) was giving them sh*t over this very issue. :)

Comment: i think there is a good reason not to allow operator overloading in a language: to prevent people from using it. it is a powerful tool and very cool for maths, but is dangerous for everything else. lazy as coders are, they tend to missuse it for shortening down code, and the moment people start performing a map multiplying an iterable with a function, or even when all arithmetic ops are defined for functions, code readability is about to reach 0. and yes, i've spent considerable amounts of time porting code like that. :-S
it's a design choice. and design choices always tend to be disputable.

Comment: Punish everyone else for a few bad apples? This is one reason I prefer C#. If I really need operator overloading it is there.

Comment: Basically, operator overloading is only really appropriate for 2-3 different situations in OOP design (Vectors, Matrices, Complex numbers).  Most other situations, it's too loosely defined and only leads to sloppy code, weak syntax, and poor documentation, even from people who know how to use it.  I think that's why Sun opted to not use it in Java, and I think that's a valid decision.

Comment: Hasn't the introduction of lambda expressions in Java 8 solved this problem? Or is there still more to it?

Comment: @MMJZ: What do lambda expressions have to do with operator overloading?

Comment: "That's just terrible." Is just an oppinion, yours and probably millions of peoples but not everyone hate OO expressions, I dont find it horrible.

Comment: Lack of operator overloading is part of what makes Java programs easier to maintain (because you need less context to understand what a given program snippet does).

Comment: Tbh. it's very little effort to write a small regex based language on top of java. Overload the operation you want, write a regex search replace mapping, and voila, you're done.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful When your argument for why the language doesn't suck at a task is that you can use it to write _another_ language that wouldn't suck, I think it's time to step back and reassess

Comment: I think a good middle ground is for the language to not allow overloading, but do overload the built in classes where it makes sense. This seems like the best of both worlds, with no downsides to legitimate use cases. I've never written a custom class that I felt would benefit from operator overloading, but it would be nice to be able to use operators on, for instance, BigDecimals.

Answer (score 27):

I think .NET had (has) a lot of the same perceived issues that Java has.  Microsoft has just done a better job at marketing to developers with XNA :-)

Comment: XNA also makes it possible to deploy your .NET application to XBox.  I haven't seen anything quite that smooth for Java.

Comment: You can also deploy to the Zune as well.

Comment: Bit of an older question, but just to update, you can now write XNA games for Windows Phone as well :-)

Comment: @JoelMartinez another update: it's not possible to write XNA games for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: @TomA It is possible now to write monogame games for WP8

Comment: "Bit if an older question, but just to update," what Windows Phones? ;)

Answer (score 19):

Minor points first:

- any productivity boost from Java is
  hypothetical. The syntax is almost
  identical to C++ so you're really
  just banking on savings from memory
  management and standard libraries.
  The libraries have little to offer
  games developers and memory
  management is a contentious issue due
  to garbage collection.
- cross-platform "for free" is not as
  good as you think because few
  developers want to use OpenGL and
  several key platforms probably lack a
  good Java implementation or wrappers
  for their native libraries, whether
  for graphics, audio, networking, etc.

But mainly, the issue is backwards compatibility. Games developers moved to C++ from C and to C from assembly purely because the migration route was smooth. Each interoperates closely with the previous, and all their previous code was usable in the new language, often via a single compiler. Therefore migration was as slow or as fast as you liked. For example, some of our old headers in use today still have *#ifdef WATCOMC* in, and I don't think anybody has used the Watcom compiler here in a decade or more. There is a massive investment in old code and each bit is only replaced as needed. That process of replacing and upgrading bits and pieces from one game to the next is nowhere near as practical if you changed to a language that doesn't natively interoperate with your existing code. Yes, C++/Java interoperability is possible, but very impractical by comparison to simply writing "C with a bit of C++" or embedding asm blocks in C.

To properly supercede C++ as the game developers' language of choice, it must do one of two things:

1. Be easily interoperable with
   existing legacy code, thus
   preserving investment and
   maintaining access to existing
   libraries and tools, OR
2. Demonstrably
   show up-front enough of a
   productivity boost that the cost of
   rewriting all your own code (or
   reworking the interfaces into
   reusable components that can be used
   from that language) is more than
   covered.

Subjectively, I don't think Java meets either of those. A higher-level language might meet the 2nd, if someone is brave enough to be the pioneer. (EVE Online is probably the best example we have of Python being usable, but which uses a fork of the main Python language, many C++ components for performance, and even that is for a fairly undemanding game in modern terms.)

Comment: Just wanted to add, EVE Online is an 'online' space simulation, where 1000s vs 1000s player vs player battles are common, which can be counted as a demanding scenario in terms of performance. Although it's speed intensive parts are written in C/C++, it's still an interesting study on the challenges of using a high level language (Python) in games.

Comment: However, remember that performance in multiplayer server-side games is measured by slightly different metrics to performance in single-player client-side games - the former is more concerned with throughput, the latter with latency.

Comment: Yep that's true, but that battles includes 2000+ ships on screen, with 2000+ projectiles(missiles, with animations), explosions etc. which requires some heavy graphics performance. Anyways, thanks for the detailed answer, it still holds true.

Comment: If you think that C & Java syntax are the same and therefore that has some relationship to performance you really don't understand what is going on.  How could C possibly decide at runtime that a given function is being called with the same parameters repeatedly and replace the entire function call with a constant while retaining the function call when there is a deviation in the parameters?  I'm not saying the runtime is always better or alwyas worse, just that it has no relationship whatsoever to the syntax!

Comment: @BillK - you appear to have misread. I mentioned syntax only with reference to 'productivity' - not to 'performance'. It's true that JIT optimizations could make Java faster in theory, but this does not occur in practice, at least not in game software.

Comment: @Kylotan You are correct, I misunderstood what you meant.  Although I still pretty seriously disagree with your points, I see that I misunderstood what you are saying.  I haven't compared typing speed to productivity in so long I forgot it was even a thing.

Answer (score 13):

- Are there any good ports of gaming engines/libraries?
- Many C/C++ developers, particularly the ones on Windows (where most commercial games are written) are familiar with Visual Studio. There is no comparison in IDEs.
- In general, Java has been sold to businesses because of it's solid typing and it has a perception of not having memory management issues.
- And yes, Java still suffers from a perception that it is slow, and it's memory management is poor, and for games, it probably is ill-suited to the task. As stated in some of the other answers, garbage collection just isn't going to cut it when you are dealing with real-time high-performance requirements. **Video games push CPUs and GPUs to their limits.**

Comment: +1 for the bold text. People don't seem to realize that when your game is running at 20 fps, it's often hardware bound at 20 fps. It really want to get to 30+ fps.. but it can't.

Comment: I don't think it's just the GC that's the problem performance-wise though...nor even that coupled with the slow startup phase...it's general performance issues, but that's just me.

Comment: I think at this point I am more likely to agree than in the past. Optimization of the JVM has improved; however, in light of the performance improvements to loosely typed languages like JavaScript and others, Java's performance in comparison is pretty inexcusable. There are plenty of apologists for the performance of Java. (but the perceived performance in the end is all that matters)'

Answer (score 13):

I'm playing the Sims 3, and I did some poking around.
The graphics engine is C++, while the scripting and behavior engine is C#/Mono.
So while C++ is there for time critical bits,  other stuff like .interaction, game logic, AI is in an object oriented managed language.

Comment: and then for the Mac version, they shove the entire thing inside a modified Wine virtual machine. Still faster than it would be in straight Java I think :-)

Comment: Wine is not a virtual machine, it is a runtime library that mimics the behavior of the Windows runtime libraries. Hence the name (Wine Is Not an Emulator).

Comment: This is very common in games, quite often logic that isn't time-critical is written in some sort of scripting language, commonly lua or python.

Comment: It's not vanilla Mono, though. EA needed a special team working on their own custom CLR full-time to make it work.

Comment: Just a side note that the Sims 3 is notorious for underperforming even on excellent computers.

Answer (score 10):

One of the biggest reasons Java and other Virtual Machine languages are not used for games is due to Garbage Collection. The same thing goes for .NET. Garbage collection has come a long ways and works great in most types of applications. In order to do garbage collection though, you do need to pause and interrupt the application to collect the trash. This can cause periodic lag when collection happens.

Java has the same problem for realtime applications. When tasks must run at a specific time, it is hard to have an automated task such as garbage collection respect that.

It is not that Java is slow. It is that Java is not good at handling realtime tasks.

Comment: You can, however, write your own scheduler for the garbage collector if you're going to go so far as to port Java to a new environment. The memory has to be reclaimed either way, and in a real-time environment, you could have the option of when to schedule your gc... best of both worlds.

I have to go back to the point that there isn't much reason to port Java over to an architecture to do the things you want it to do when C/C++ already do those things for you. Java shines in other places.

Comment: This is not the 1990s. Garbage collectors are pretty good now when tuned for low pause.

Answer (score 8):

A large reason is that video games require direct knowledge of the hardware underneath, often times, and there really is no great implementation for many architectures. It's the knowledge of the underlying hardware architecture that allows developers to squeeze every ounce of performance out of a gaming system. Why would you take the time to port Java to a gaming platform, and then write a game on top of that port when you could just write the game?

edit: this is to say that it's more than a "speed" or "don't have the right libraries" issue. Those two things go hand-in-hand with this, but it's more a matter of "how do I make a system like the cell b.e. run my java code? there aren't really any good java compilers that can manage the pipelines and vectors like i need.."

Answer (score 7):

Performance issue is the first reason. When you see the kind of hyper optimized C++ code that are in the Quake engines ( http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/9 ), you know they're not gonna waste their time with a virtual machine.

Sure there may be some .NET games (which ones ? I'm interested. Are there some really CPU/GPU-intensive ones ?), but I guess it's more because lot of people are experts in MS technologies and followed Microsoft when they launched their new technology.

Oh and cross-platform just isn't in the mind of video games companies. Linux is just around 1% of market, Mac OS a few % more. They definitely think it's not worth dumping Windows-only technologies and librairies such as DirectX.

Comment: "cross-platform just isn't in the mind of video games companies" -- That's why I fully respect the companies that do. :)

Comment: I'm definitely grateful to Carmack for being so committed to both cross-platform and open-source. I simply stated what most companies think.

Comment: That's true. You don't see a lot of popular video games ported to Linux. :(

Comment: Cross-platform is not just cross OS. Think of PS3, Xbox 360, Wii.

Comment: "they're not gonna waste their time with a virtual machine." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_III_Arena#Virtual_machine, Carmack built his own for the game logic.

Comment: I know it's late but I realized I never answered your question about which games are written on top of the .NET Framework. The one I was referring to specifically was Far Cry 2--some of it uses the .NET Framework (admittedly, I don't know how much, so it could very well be just some non-important part of the map logic or something).

Comment: Supposedly Sim City Societies was coded in .NET; can't remember whether or not it was C# or VB.NET but anyway the graphics were quite nice. God-awful game though.. did a remarkable disservice to the Sim City series.

Answer (score 5):

Misconceptions about performance and poor JVM optimizations would be my guess. I say misconceptions about performance because there are some Java ports of C++ games that perform faster than their C++ counterparts (see Jake 2). The real problem, IMHO, is that many Java programmers aren't focused so much on bleeding edge performance as they are with ease of use and understandability/maintainability of code. On the C/C++ side of things you're essentially coding in a slightly higher level assembly language and its about as close to the hardware as you can get without writing in assembly or straight machine code.

Comment: If it's "about as close to the hardware as you can get without writing in assembly", then Java won't be able to beat it, unless your coding is terrible. The closer you get to the hardware, the faster you're going to be able to get.

Answer (score 4):

You can ask why web applications aren't written in C or C++, too. The power of Java lies in its network stack and object oriented design. Of course C and C++ have that, too. But on a lower abstraction. Thats nothing negative, but you don't want to reinvent the wheel every time, do you?

Java also has no direct hardware access, which means you are stuck with the API of any frameworks.

Comment: Java can call native code through "JNI"

Comment: ... and lose portability while you're at it!

Comment: You really don't lose much portability when you use JNI.  Provided that you are still able to compile the native libraries on platforms you want to support, it basically just means you only have to port/recompile 1% of your code rather than all of it.  You still get a lot of benefit from Java's portability.

Answer (score 4):

[List of game engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) on Wikipedia lists many game engines along with the programming language that they are written in.

**There are several Java game engines listed.**

Clicking some of the links will lead you to examples of games and demos written in Java.  Here's a couple:

- [Ardor3D](http://ardor3d.com/)
- [Bytonic Software](http://bytonic.de/html/jake2.html)

For certain games and situations, Java's trade-offs might be acceptable.

Comment: I know games *exist* that are written in Java. But besides Minecraft and Runescape, very few mainstream commercial games are written for the Java platform. How many AAA titles were written in Java? And why so few? Hence my question.

Answer (score 3):

.NET definitely has some of the same issues that Java has when it comes to intense 3D performance. Microsoft has also invested a lot more time and money in the development of the libraries when it comes to working with 3D heavy operations.

(...personally, I also think they had a leg up when it comes to the magic between DirectX and .NET)

Answer (score 3):

1. Java is slow, most of the heavy lifting is not handled by the GPU.  There's still animation, physics, and AI hitting the CPU, all of which are very time-consuming.
2. Java doesn't exist on consoles, and consoles are a major target for commercial games.  If you use Java on PC, you're eliminating your ability to port to consoles within reasonable time and budget.
3. Many of the more experienced coders in the game industry have been using C and C++ long before Java became popular.  The two points above may contribute to this, but I expect that many professional game coders just don't really know Java all that well.
4. Someone else's point about middleware above was a good one, so I'm adding it to my answer.  There's a lot of legacy code and middleware written specifically to link with C/C++, and last I checked Java doesn't have good interoperability.  Using Java for most companies would involve throwing out a lot of code, much of which has been paid for in one way or another.

Comment: You can use JavaCL, JOCL, or APARAPI to offload a lot of that to the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that speed is still the issue.  Cross platform is going to be an issue isn't it since you don't know what 3d card is available when you write the code?  Does java have anything to support auto discovery of 3d capabilities?  And I'd guess that there are tools to ease porting a game between the wii, xbox, and ps3, but expensive I'll bet.

The ps3 has java, via the blue ray support.  Check the bd-j site.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is very possible for managed code to do 3d games, the problem is the back engines. With .Net, for a brief period, there was a Managed DirectX wrapper to DirectX 9 by Microsoft. This was before the abstraction that is now XNA.

Being given total access to DirectX api's, .Net games work a treat. The best example I know of is www.entombed.co.uk, which is written in VB.Net.

Unfortunately, on the Java side, it is seriously lacking - mainly for the reason that DirectX isn't available for Java, and games programmers know and understand the DirectX api - why learn yet another api when you will be returning to DirectX?

Answer (score 2):

Game marketing is a commercial process; publishers want quantifiable low-risk returns on their investment.
As a consequence, the focus is usually on technology gimmicks (with exceptions) that consumers will buy to produce reliable return - these tend to be superficial visual effects such as lens glare or higher resolution.
These effects are reliable because they simply use increases in processing power - they exploit the hardware/Moore's law increases.
this implies using C/C++ - java is usually too abstracted from the hardware to exploit these benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Even games written on the .Net platform are often highly optimized for speed like direct access to memory and bus. .Net allows to use C / C++ and mix it with higher level languages such as C#.

Game development studios often work close together with hardware vendors, which do provide access to low level interfaces of their products. This is a world, where you have to use ASM and C for device communication. A virtual environment would slow down these program parts.

Anyway, modern 3D games in fact do use higher level languages. Often, you'll find the game logic written in languages like Lua or Python. But the core (I/O, threads, task scheduling) of the typical 3D game will be written in low level languages for the next 25 years or as long devices do not allow abstraction and virtualization by themself (which will come).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other posts about leveraging elements of a preexisting/licensed codebase, performance, etc.

One thing I'd like to add is it's hard to pull nasty DRM tricks through a virtual machine.

Also I think there's a hubris component where project managers think they can make stable/reliable code with C++ with all the perks like having absolute control over their tools and resources, BUT without all the negatives that complicate and bog down their competition because "we're smarter than they are".

Answer (score 0):

Runescape by Jagex is written in Java, the "video game" tag might not specifically apply it being an on-line game, but it does have a decent following.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really answer my question at all.

Comment: But the blind statement of the question leads to the assumption that NO games are written in Java, just pointing out the successful case of where one is.

Answer (score -2):

It was talked about it a lot already, u can find even on Wiki the reasons...

- C/C++ for the game engine and all intensive stuff.
- Lua or Python for scripting in the game.
- Java - very-very bad performance, big memory usage + it's not available on Game Consoles(It is used for some very simple games(Yes, Runescape counts in here, it's not Battlefield or Crysis or what else is there) just because there are a lot of programmers that know this programming language).
- C# - big memory usage(It is used for some very simple games just because there are pretty much programmers that know this programming language).

And I hear more and more Java programmers that try to convince people that Java is not slow, it is not slow for drawing a widget on the screen and drawing some ASCII characters on the widget, to receive and send data through network(And it is recommended to use it in this cases(network data manipulation) instead of C/C++)... But it is damn slow when it comes to serious stuff like math calculations, memory allocation/manipulation and a lot of this good stuff.

I remember an article on MIT site where they show what C/C++ can do if u use the language and compiler features: A matrix multiplier(2 matrices), 1 implementation in Java and 1 implementation in C/C++, with C/C++ features and appropriate compiler optimisations activated, the C/C++ implementation was ~296 260 times faster than the Java implementation.

I hope you understand now why people use C/C++ instead of Java in games, imagine Crysis in Java, there would not be any computer in this world which could handle that... + Garbage collection works ok for Widgets which just destroyed an image but it's still cached in there and needs to be cleaned but not for games, for sure, u will have even more lags on every garbage collection activation.

**Edit**: Because somebody asked for the article, here, I searched in the web archive to get that, I hope you are satisfied...[MIT Case Study](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/74613/6-172-fall-2009/contents/lecture-notes/MIT6_172F09_lec01.pdf)

And to add, no, Java for gaming is still an awful idea. Just a few days ago a big company that I will not name started rewriting their game **client** from Java to C++ because a very simple game(In terms of Graphics) was lagging and heating i7 Laptops with powerful nVidia GT 5xx and 6xx generation video cards(not only nVidia, the point here is that this powerful cards that can handle on Max settings most of the new games and can't handle this game) and the memory consumption was ~2.5 - 2.6 GB Ram. For such simple graphics it needs a beast of a machine.

Comment: You clearly know very little about the modern Java runtime and virtual machine. The article you mentioned is more than likely from a decade ago or more, of course no one can know because you didn't cite it. Your perception of Java is outdated.

Comment: Ow, you want a citation, Ok, no problem...

Comment: Ok so that study proves that for large scale matrix multiplication Java loses to C when 2-dimensional array access is being used to access data.  Yes I would've guessed that too.  And if that really is a problem for you, which I doubt it would be, that's why you have JNI.  The bounds checking overhead for arrays does add up in that situation, although his Java code could've been optimized to significantly improve results.  Likewise, I question his understanding of JIT when he states, "faster compilation = not the best code generated."  Go read IBM's specification's to prove otherwise.

Comment: Java is NOT a bad choice for game development.  There are a lot of successful games out there that run Java.  Typically, you do need a little bit of help from native code (especially with LWJGL and such) to really get the best results.  But if I only have to port and recompile 1% of my code rather than 100%, that sounds like a great deal to me.

Comment: @bgroenks "100%" - looks like you have no idea about C/C++... And when making a game you can always use a cross-platform library(SDL and a bunch of others) or framework(Qt for example). For example: EA uses Qt for absolutely every game they have... Qt is WAY more cross-platform than Java and it compiles to native code.

Comment: Of course there are libraries and frameworks available for C game development, just like there are for Java.  I mean I love C, don't get me wrong.  But I'd much rather write most of the game code (or at least the engine) in Java because of the development time and better maintainability.  Why is that wrong?  My point is that Java is a perfectly viable option for games.  It doesn't need a beast of a machine to be successful if you know what you're doing.  The same goes for every other language ever invented....

Comment: I don't really see the point in Java when you have Qt. I find Qt code more clear, easier to understand and maintain than Java code. When I ask my friends why they are so afraid of C++ they always tell me that they hate pointers and making sure to deallocate memory. Looks like a lot of people don't know about shared_ptr in C++... For me, Qt and C# .NET/C++ .NET are the nicest to write in. Java code usually is very bloated with exception handling, has usually outdated libraries(It is doing good mostly only on the server side but the rest...) and frequently outdated documentation.

Comment: As a side note, I actually love pointers.  They can be frustrating as hell to work with, but they really are pretty fascinating.  Java code, however, when written by convention is still more robust and maintainable.  Of course some of it does still come down to personal opinion.  Exception handling is really quite easy to handle outside of the main code to prevent it from becoming bloated, whether through the use of "throws" or fail-methods.  I don't really like .NET, partly because I don't want to feed the Windows tirade, so for a cross-platform game, I would rather work with Java.

Comment: Sorry I'm late to the party. The MIT pdf which was referenced showed a ~1.9x performance advantage of C over the "no object" java implementation. Problem is, the "no object" java implementation is wrong: There are no 2D arrays in java. They are arrays of array objects. That means each read is two reads with an indirection and same with writes. It can be done with one array and the author didn't figure it out. The fact that this mistake made it into an MIT document is cringe.