# Java High Graphics 3D Games?

Tags: java

Why are there no "High Graphics 3D games" made with Java on the market? Isn't Java a good option? And why so? The only big game i've seen is basically Minecraft, and there can't be a large amount of polygons and lighting/physics-engines in that one. Still a relatively good pc is needed? There are games incredibly more graphics heavy than Minecraft and stills runs faster. I suppose Java "wastes" resources. Anyway, the question is: Is it possible to make good graphics application with Java, or why not.

Answer (score 5):

> The game development world is a funny one: On one hand, they're often
>   quick to accept new ideas, on the other hand, they're still in the
>   stone age.
>
> The truth is, there's rarely that much incentive in switching to
>   .NET/Java/anything other than C/C++.
>
> Most game companies license parts of the game engine from other
>   companies. These parts are written in C++, and although you might have
>   access to the source so you could port it, that takes a lot of effort
>   (and of course, the license needs to allow it).
>
> Also, a lot of legacy code already exists in C++. If code from
>   previous projects can be reused (say, if you're writing a sequel),
>   that counts even more in favor of sticking with the same language,
>   instead of rewriting it in a new language (more so since you'll likely
>   reintroduce a ton of bugs which you'll need to spend time ironing out.
>
> Finally, it's rare for games to be written in 100% C++ anyway - a lot
>   is done using scripting languages, whether they're custom or just
>   integrating an existing languages (Lua being one of the more popular
>   ones these days).
>
> As far as garbage collection is concerned, that can be a bit of a
>   problem. The problem is not so much that it exists, it's more how it
>   works - the garbage collector MUST be non-blocking (or at least be
>   guaranteed to only block very briefly), since it's simply unacceptable
>   to have the game freeze for 10 seconds while it scans all the
>   allocated memory to see what can be freed. I know Java tends to choke
>   quite a bit in GC'ing when it's close to running out of memory (and
>   for some games out there, it will).
>
> You're also a bit more restricted in what you can do: you can't fully
>   exploit the hardware due to the overhead of the runtime. Imagine
>   Crysis being written in Java... even if that's the only visible
>   difference, it just wouldn't be the same (I'm also pretty sure you'd
>   need a Core i7 to run it.).
>
> This doesn't mean these languages don't have their place in game
>   development - and no, I'm not just referring to tool programming. For
>   most games, you don't need that extra bit of performance you get from
>   C++, including 3D games, and if you're writing it all from scratch, it
>   can make perfect sense to use something like XNA - in fact, there's a
>   good chance it will.
>
> As far as commercial games are concerned - does [RuneScape](http://runescape.com) count?
>   That may well be the most succesful Java game out there.

Source: [Why are only a few video games written in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034458/why-arent-video-games-written-in-java?rq=1)

Comment: Modern graphics cards do most of the work.  Hence raw speed of the actual implementation language running on the CPU is not as crucial as it used to be as long as they can keep the GPU fed.

Comment: The additional JNI overhead, though, does have a minor performance impact. If you're doing it "right" and batching your draw calls as much as possible it should be negligible.